# discord.js Receiving Missing Access error when trying to cache guild

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm getting this error in console:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Missing Access
```

when I'm trying to cache a guild using this code:

```
await invite.guild.fetch()
const inviteGuild = message.client.guilds.cache.get(invite.guild.id);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because the bot doesn't have needed permissions to retrieve guild information. Try giving Administrator permissions on the [Discord Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications).

More information about Discord.JS Errors [here](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/errors.html)

Comment: I've tried that but I'm still getting the same error

Comment: Are you able to help?